# How is synchronous I/O implemented in Node?

Tags: node.js

I am curious to know what is happening in Node when making a synchronous I/O call. I read [this](https://www.daveeddy.com/2013/03/26/synchronous-file-io-in-nodejs/) and from what it seems,

> fs.writeFileSync is synchronous in the sense that it blocks the event
>   loop while it executes. It does NOT ask the Kernel to do a synchronous
>   write to the underlying file system.

I can't, however, find in the [code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/fs.js#L489) what part is causing this to be read synchronously. I don't quite understand how, if there's no blocking `write` syscall, how it's blocking the event loop. Is it just busy waiting until `write` returns? Or is Node actually doing work during that time that the `write(2)` or `read(2)` happens?

Or maybe I'm misunderstanding what is meant above by "synchronous writes". I would think of a synchronous write as a call to `write(2)` which blocks, and an "asynchronous write" as one being, say, passed `O_NONBLOCK` and returns immediately.

Comment: https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/0481a7f3b883862cadf963314d23490adc6656a4/lib/fs.js#L1201 and https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/

Have a read here about writeFileSync(), writeSync(), openSync(), closeSync() and in later read about the event loop and process.nexttick() at the bottom. Just some context you may get idea from.

Comment: Thank you @AtishShakya. I do understand the idea of the event loop and `nextTick` - however, that would be for asynchronous calls, which I understand. I don't exactly understand how node is doing synchronous calls to the filesystem (i.e. blocking the event loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the `read` and `readSync` methods, the difference is that the *async* version creates a wrapper that will call the callback, and will add a `FSReqCallback` in the `binding.read` method call, whereas the *sync* version will pass `undefined` as callback, plus another argument (an empty object).

I think `binding.read` will return immediately depending on the presence of the `FSReqCallback` parameter.

However, I am not able to locate the method that uses the `FSReqCallback` paramter.